# Should the GraphicsPath be disposed after use

Tags: c#, winforms, memory, graphicspath

I am making some utility classes that make different types of symbols to place onto an elevation of CAD drawings.
I want to make sure that if I need to dispose of the GraphicsPath object that I do so.

In the code below from inside the getCircle function it shows that I am passing the myPath "GraphicsPath" object to the AddStringToPath function.

I cannot use the using(){} scope for this because I am passing the myPath graphics object as a ref.

Is this design ok to use or do I need to go about this a different way to ensure garbage collection?

```
GraphicsPath getCircle(Graphics dc, string text = "")
{
    GraphicsPath myPath = new GraphicsPath();
    myPath.AddEllipse(symbolCircle);
    AddStringToPath(dc, ref myPath, text);
    return myPath;
}

void AddStringToPath(Graphics dc, ref GraphicsPath path, string text)
{
    SizeF textSize = dc.MeasureString(text, elevFont);
    var centerX = (path.GetBounds().Width / 2) - (textSize.Width / 2);
    var centerY = (path.GetBounds().Height / 2) - (textSize.Height / 2);

    // Add the string to the path.
    path.AddString(text,
        elevFont.FontFamily,
        (int)elevFont.Style,
        elevFont.Size,
        new PointF(centerX + 2, centerY + 2),
        StringFormat.GenericDefault);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your function which creates the path should be used later in a using statement

```
 using(var path = getCircle(dc, "Text"))
 {
      // do something with path
 }
```

it would also be better, if you would call the function `CreateCircle` instead of `getCircle`

Comment: Thank you. Plus a much better naming convention.

Comment: which is better,  `var path =` or `GraphicsPath path=`?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the pass the path as `ref` here. `ref` would only be useful if you wanted to change what `path` points to in the calling function. Get rid of the `ref` and add `using` as usual.

And read up on value types and reference types and what `ref` is actually useful for.

Comment: +1. Note that `using` for path should be at the place that calls `getCircle`, not *insisde* `getCircle` that I feel from reading your question.

Comment: If you notice I am creating the path in getCircle and operating on that path in AddStringToPath. I believe I've got it right.

Comment: @Storefront: Please do as I suggested and read up on what `ref` actually does. `GraphicsPath` is a reference type.